# What should be suitable configuration to set up 2-3 node hadoop cluster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

What should be suitable configuration to set up 2-3 node hadoop cluster on AWS ?

I want to set-up Hive, HBase, Solr, Tomcat on hadoop cluster with purpose of doing small POC's.

Also please suggest option to go with EMR or with EC2 and manually set up cluster on that.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon EMR** can deploy a multi-node cluster with Hadoop and various applications (eg Hive, HBase) within a few minutes. It is much easier to deploy and manage than trying to deploy your own Hadoop cluster under Amazon EC2.

See: [Getting Started: Analyzing Big Data with Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-gs.html)